# Solving parametric function numerically for positive values

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

So I have a function `f1[x,y]` that includes a parameter `c`. I would like to solve the corresponding `f1[x,y]==0` for positive x and y (depending on `c`), with the further restriction that `c>=0`, but I do not know how to encode all of this properly.

My try was:

```
Reduce[f[x,y]==0 && x>0 && y>0 &&c>=0, {x,y}]
```

But it does not seem to work (it is stuck "running"), while playing around a little bit `NSolve[f[x,y]==0, {x,y}]/. -> c=1`, or any positive `c` have many solutions, among which some for positive `x` and `y`. Conversely, also `NSolve[f[x,y]==0 &&x>0 && y>0, {x,y}]/. -> c=1` is stuck running. Am I doing something wrong?

To completely reproduce the framework I am using I would have to add many useless stuff, so I've worked out a minimal reproduction of the problem I have using two functions:

```
f1[x_, y_] := (50 (2 p^6 (20 + y) - p^2 (-2 + x) x^3 (20 + 3 y) + 
    p^4 x (3 x (-20 + y) + 2 (60 + y))))/((p^2 + x^2)^3 (20 + y))
f2[x_, y_] := (p^4 (20 + y)^2 + x^4 (20 + y)^2 + 
  2 p^2 x^2 (1400 - 1000 x + 40 y + y^2))/((p^2 + x^2)^2 (20 + y)^2)

NSolve[f1[x, y] == 0 &&  f2[x, y] == 0, {x, y}] /. p -> 4
```

Where the NSolve gives as output:

```
{{x -> 1.01264, y -> -18.804}, {x -> 5.21585, 
  y -> 24.3412}, {x -> 6.26257, y -> -66.5406}, {x -> 179.176, 
  y -> -7.27542}, {x -> -4.13331 - 0.549203 I, 
  y -> -22.4456 + 51.1497 I}, {x -> -4.13331 + 0.549203 I, 
  y -> -22.4456 - 51.1497 I}, {x -> -0.112599 - 2.93525 I, 
  y -> 91.3789 + 57.5289 I}, {x -> -0.112599 + 2.93525 I, 
  y -> 91.3789 - 57.5289 I}, {x -> 0.412582 - 2.45391 I, 
  y -> -55.0916 - 58.626 I}, {x -> 0.412582 + 2.45391 I, 
  y -> -55.0916 + 58.626 I}}
```

Where the second one is clearly positive. However, `NSolve[f1[x, y] == 0 &&  f2[x, y] == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}] /.  p -> 4` does not find it and remains stuck. At the same time, `Reduce` finds roots in the unbounded case and not in the bounded one.

Comment: I should also mention that I do not expect any explicit closed form solutions due to the nature of the function: I'd be happy with positive roots, which do exist (actually, plenty of them according to the first NSolve).

Comment: If you reasonably restrict search for solutions with `Reduce` you should be able to find them. However without definition of `f` there is nothing to say. If `f` is too complicated try to provide another  example that one might go ahead with.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a syntax problem (since I am just starting out)... If this is not the case then why `NSolve[f[x,y]==0, {x,y}]\.c->1` provides me with many solutions with some positive and `NSolve[f[x,y]==0 &&x>0 && y>0, {x,y}]\.c->1` is stuck running? I mean there is no reason for the solutions of the second not to be a subset of the first, if I am not making errors with the coding

Comment: Typically you need to present a minimal example so that we can work on it.

Comment: @Artes Hey hey there's no need to be rude on the internet... I am here precisely because I am a beginner and I wanted some clarification, no need to flex on your superior understanding: I am trying to learn stuff cmon. I've edited the question, hope it sounds "less stupid".

Comment: @yarchik I've tried to add one without too much useless context, the problem is equivalent to the one I showed editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSolve[f1[x, y] == 0 && f2[x, y] == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, 
  Reals] /. p -> 4
```

plot:

```
f1[x_, y_] := (50 (2 p^6 (20 + y) - p^2 (-2 + x) x^3 (20 + 3 y) + 
      p^4 x (3 x (-20 + y) + 2 (60 + y))))/((p^2 + x^2)^3 (20 + y))
f2[x_, y_] := (p^4 (20 + y)^2 + x^4 (20 + y)^2 + 
    2 p^2 x^2 (1400 - 1000 x + 40 y + y^2))/((p^2 + x^2)^2 (20 + 
       y)^2)
ContourPlot[{f1[x, y] == 0, f2[x, y] == 0} /. p -> 4 // Evaluate, {x, 
  0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: It does work like a charm in both the NSolve and Reduce problems... I wonder what happens at the algorithmic level for this to be pivotal. That's the answer though, thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

It also works with [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[x_, y_] := (50 (2 p^6 (20 + y) - p^2 (-2 + x) x^3 (20 + 3 y) + 
       p^4 x (3 x (-20 + y) + 2 (60 + y))))/((p^2 + x^2)^3 (20 + y));

f2[x_, y_] := (p^4 (20 + y)^2 + x^4 (20 + y)^2 + 
     2 p^2 x^2 (1400 - 1000 x + 40 y + y^2))/((p^2 + x^2)^2 (20 + y)^2);

eqns = {f1[x, y] == 0, f2[x, y] == 0, x > 0, y > 0, p >= 0};
```

The solutions are [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)s involving [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
sol[p_] = Solve[eqns, {x, y}];
```

However, it will evaluate to numeric values for specific values of `p` meeting the specified conditions.

```
sol /@ Range[1., 4.]

(* {{{x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}}, {{x -> 3.05436, 
   y -> 9.37664}}, {{x -> 4.11556, y -> 17.575}}, {{x -> 5.21585, 
   y -> 24.3412}}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[{y, x} /. sol[p]], {p, 0, 4},
  AxesLabel -> {p, None},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{y, x}, {0.75, 0.4}]] // Quiet
```

[image]